# How to delete Laravel file from storage on Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I have written the code below to delete a file both from DB and from storage. The issue is only the db record is being deleted and the storage file remains. No errors or anything are coming up. It just looks like the delete from storage code is just skipped.

```
public function destroy($id)
{           
    $delete = CompanyDocument::find($id);
    $filepath = ('/storage/app/documents/companies/'.$delete->document);
    Storage::delete($filepath); //delete from storage

    $delete->delete(); //delete from DB

    return back();
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need to specify `/storage/app` when deleting files

Comment: Do you tried this : `Storage::delete('documents/companies' . '/' . $delete->document);` because `\Storage` refers to `/storage/app/`

Comment: You should hook into the deleting model event, instead of manually deleting in your controller

Comment: @DovBenyominSohacheski How do I do that? I have tried the scopeDelete in my Model and calling it from controller but it is not working.

Comment: @EdenWebStudio I posted an answer that utilizes model events

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final solution that worked.

```
$delete = CompanyDocument::find($id);       
    Storage::delete('documents/companies'.'/'.$delete->document); //delete from storage
    $delete->delete(); //delete from DB
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually deleting the stored document from the controller every time, hook into [Laravel's Model Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events).

In the `CompanyDocument` class, you should override the `boot` method and listen for deletion.

**CompanyDocument**

```
class CompanyDocument extends Model {
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot(); 

        static::deleting(function($deleted) {
            Storage::delete("documents/companies/{$deleted->document}");
        });
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function destroy(CompanyDocument $document)
{           
    $document->delete();
    return back();
}
```

Comment: So in my controller do i then use '$delete = CompanyDocument::find($id);
    $delete->delete();' to trigger the boot function..?

Comment: @EdenWebStudio just updated to include the controller